# How can I horizontally center rows in CollectionView with sections

Tags: uicollectionview, swift4

So I know this topic has been tackled in the past, still, I have try'd applying all previous suggestions but non have actually solved my issue.

I have a `collectionView` that contains a dynamic amount of sections and items and I need to constraint all rows to be horizontally centered.

I have try'd to apply a pod called `KTCenterFlowLayout` but with no success since apparently it doesn't work well with a multi section `collectionView`.

Is there anyway to center collectionView rows in a multi sectional `CollectionView` in **swift4**?

Answer (score 0):

```
'func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let screenWidth = (UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-4) / 3


    return CGSize(width:screenWidth , height: screenWidth);

}'
```

Write it down that in your View Controller and set that you whatever thing that you want..[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Los9E.png)